# Download large files via VBscript

Tags: vbscript

Has anyone been successful with downloading large files via VBScript?  My script is below and it is erroring out downloading a file over a 1GB.  Small files it works with no problem.  Do I need to try a different method?  The error message it gives me is below.  Thanks in advance for any suggestions!

```
strFileURL = "http://10.0.0.0/File.zip"
strHDLocation = "C:\File.zip"


Set objXMLHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")

objXMLHTTP.open "GET", strFileURL, false
objXMLHTTP.setTimeouts 1000 * 60 * 60, 1000 * 60 * 60, 1000 * 60 * 60, 1000 * 60 * 60
objXMLHTTP.send()

If objXMLHTTP.Status = 200 Then
  Set objADOStream = CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
  objADOStream.Open
  objADOStream.Type = 1 'adTypeBinary

  objADOStream.Write objXMLHTTP.ResponseBody
  objADOStream.Position = 0    'Set the stream position to the start

  Set objFSO = Createobject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
If objFSO.Fileexists(strHDLocation) Then objFSO.DeleteFile strHDLocation

  objADOStream.SaveToFile strHDLocation
  objADOStream.Close
  Set objADOStream = Nothing
End if

Set objXMLHTTP = Nothing
Set objFSO = Nothing
```

The error message I receive is:

```
Error: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation.
Code: 8007000E
Source: msxml3.dll
```

Answer (score 2):

"Error: Not enough storage is available to complete this operation."

Have you checked to ensure that you actually have enough disk space for the download file?

Comment: Yes, the problem is not the disk space.  Disk is 80% free.  That error message has to be pertaining to something else rather than the disk space.

Comment: Then you might look through the possible VB Script settings for any possible limits which might need to be raised. Also check the possible "temp" settings/definitions to ensure it is not parked somewhere which may be attributing to the situation.